# onesignal plugin not working for cordova ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, native

Hello i have installed onesignal plugin and code according to setup but then also it shows that plugin not installed in ionic 3 so can you please answer my question how it is possible to run this version of plugin in ionic 3 project specified some information as below .

```
"@ionic-native/onesignal": "^4.20.0",
"onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.11.4"
```

tried platform add and remove and again installed the onesignal plugin but same error that plugin not installed